# Error grabbing location data from array within fetch method

Tags: reactjs

I want to pull lat/long coordinates from the location state, however i'm getting an error saying cannot read properties of undefined [0].

I called the get location function within the weather function, is there something i'm missing?

```
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import { useState } from "react";

const WeatherCard = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  // function gets users location, and sets it to location state
  const getLocation = () => {
    // uses navigator to get location
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((location) => {
    // sets lat/long position to state[array]
    setLocation([location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude]);
    });
  };

  // function to get weather data from api
  const getWeather = () => {
    // calls getLocation function
    getLocation();
    // fetches weather data from api
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${location[0]}&lon=${location[1]}&exclude={part}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
    // takes data and parses it to json
    .then(res => res.json())
    // sets weather data to console
    .then(data => console.log(data))
  }

  // renders the weather card
  return (
    <Card>
      <div>{location}</div>
      <button onClick={getWeather}>Click</button>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default WeatherCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

The geolocation API is async, so fix the getLocation function to async:

```
const getLocation = async () => {
    // uses navigator to get location
    await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((location) => {
    // sets lat/long position to state[array]
    setLocation([location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude]);
    });
  };
```

Comment: I tried this, and had the same error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hooks-8cxjx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: and you need to allow it in your browser ;)

Comment: Checked out your codepen, and it's a blank template? It is allowed in my browser.

Comment: sorry wasnt saved , try again  :)

Comment: after you click the browser will ask for permission to know loacation, then it will show you the location

Comment: I checked it out, I have the same code but its giving me that error.

Comment: Apparently I was missing the location &&? I'm not sure how this relates, but its fixed now

Comment: its just a check to make sure you have the location. If location exists so proceed to the fetch method